# Centering elements in CSS without using Flexbox or Grid

Tags: css

I'm trying to center a div horizontally and vertically on a webpage, but I need to do it without using Flexbox or Grid. Are there alternative methods or techniques in CSS that I can use to achieve centering without relying on these newer layout systems?

I need to do it without using Flexbox or Grid

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Could you elaborate on what concrete "older system that does support neither grid nor flex" are you targetting, what you need to achieve and what have you tried? Answers in the linked question most probably covers most systems imaginable, but in case your use case is really not covered there, providing better context could help reopening this one.

Answer (score -2):

**centering a div**, probably the most asked question since ever html/css exists . You should have found plenty answers . funny question=>funny answer

---

Yes there was ways , below 2 ways without positionning:

display oldish method

```css
html {
display:table;
width:100%;
table-layout:fixed;
height:100vh;
/* see me */
background:linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%, transparent 50%);
}
body {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
}
div {
display:inline-block;
border:solid;
padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<div>center me via display <br>not flex nor grid </div>
```

or via a pseudo (was efficient with IE5 no pseudo "but an html tag" nor vh units but 100% on html,body, and display:inline+zoom:1 ... but was at 99.99999999...999% used an *evil* html table :) )

```css
body{
margin:0;
text-align:center;
/* se me */
background:linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%, transparent 50%);
}
body::before, div {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}
div {
border:solid;
padding:1em;
}
body:before {
content:'';
height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div>center me via a pseudo</div>
```